# get the last part of url (.htaccess)

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I want to get the last part of the url as a GET request (with htaccess RewriteRule) like the following :

```
http://localhost/services/rest/users/availability/detailed/Player
```

to :

```
http://localhost/services/rest/users/availability/detailed?name=player
```

I have tried :

```
RewriteRule ^detailed/(.*)$ index.php?name=$1
```

Comment: The ^ in your RewriteRule anchors the pattern to the beginning of the URL. But there's a whole bunch in the URL before `detailed`. Also, your rewrite result is going to give something that looks nothing like what you've stated you want your URL to look like. Something like (untested) `RewriteRule ^(.*/detailed)/(.*)$ $1?name=$2` would be closer.

Comment: Server error!
 Error 500

Comment: Well, I did say it was untested. :-) Do the error logs help to fine tune it?

Comment: Where is this `.htaccess` file? Does the URL map to a physical directory (which bits)?